# Systemd automount with custom command

Tags: systemd, mount, automounting

I use [tomb](https://www.dyne.org/software/tomb/) to store some files. I want to use a systemd `.automount` unit so that whenever I try to access these files, the tomb is automatically mounted. However, tombs are not mounted with `mount`, they are `tomb open` does its own specialized setup (of which `mount`ing is only one part).

Is there any way to specify a custom command for systemd `.mount`/`.automount` units? Failing that, is it possible to use other units for the same purpose?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a mount helper (see `man 8 mount`). If you specify the fs type as, say, `mytombfs` then when you or systemd mounts the filesystem it will run `/sbin/mount.mytombfs` passing it most of the options needed. This script can then do whatever you need to, and eventually call `/bin/mount "$@"` to really mount the device. For example, the .mount unit

```
[Mount]
What=/dev/sdc1
Where=/a/b
Type=mytombfs
Options=x-systemd.automount,auto,noatime,uid=meuh
```

will run

```bsh
/sbin/mount.mytombfs /dev/sdc1 /a/b -o rw,noatime,uid=1000
```